# How to properly show a pop up dialog using html/jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, dialog, popup

With this code I want to show a jQuery UI dialog when I click on a button. However, the text of the dialog is shown for a brief time when the page loads. What is the right way to implement this? 
My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">  
    </head>
    <body>
      .. html code ..
      <button id="helpbutton" title="">Help</button>

      <div id="helpdialog" title="Help dialog">
        <p>Text in the dialog will be visible for a short time when the page loads</p>
      </div>

      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="myJsFile.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

as you can see, I call my external scripts just before the end of the  for performance reasons.

myJsFile.js:

```
    //Fire up the help dialog when the help button is pressed
    jQuery(function() {
      jQuery( "#helpdialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false
      }); 
      jQuery( "#helpbutton" ).click(function() {
        jQuery( "#helpdialog" ).dialog( "open" );
      });
    });
```

**Solution** (thanks to krzmig): Use this CSS code in the CSS file or in the  section

```
  #helpdialog {
    display: none;
  }
```

Comment: Any errors in console ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvr53ob5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you load UI jQuery JS and CSS? Like in this example:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
        <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

source: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

---

edit:

For not showing dialog box when site is loading put to your CSS file code:

```css
#helpdialog {
  display: none;
}
```

or add to `<head>` section if you don't have external CSS.

```html
<style>
#helpdialog {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: yes, I load the CSS in the head and jQuery Ui (and other stuff) before the end of the body (so my structure is different than the example in jQuery UI). I edit my problem description.

Answer (score 0):

**First** include `jquery` as well.
**Second** place your scripts before your dialog in `html` so that it **loads and hides the dialog before** it could show up itself on your page. Here's the code (keep your `myJsFile.js` intact):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <button id="helpbutton" title="">Help</button>

      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="myJsFile.js"></script>


      <div id="helpdialog" title="Help dialog">
        <p>Text in the dialog will NOT! be visible for a short time when the page loads</p>
      </div>

    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but putting the <div> after my scripts does not help. I already had jQuery included (and I edited my problem description)

Answer (score 0):

You also need to include jquery main library. The required includes are jquery library, jquery ui js, and jquery ui css.

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="myJsFile.js"></script
```